# How to show a progress bar inside an Image View while uploading an image in Android?

Tags: android, progress-bar

Currently, when I am uploading an Image in Android, the entire screen goes blank and the image loads after some time. I would like to change that and make sure that there is just a progress bar inside the ImageView which shows how much of the image upload has been done(Something similar to Whats'app) and then display the image once the upload is done. How do I do that?

Edit:

I do know how to use progress bar, but the problem I face here is that my ImageActivity is a separate activity and I am calling it from a different activity to upload the image. The activity from where I am calling from is the one that should display the progress bar. Thus, not able to do that. Not able to get the progress from the other activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below link for upload the files to show the progress bar!

[Upload progress bar in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103377/upload-progress-bar-in-android)

Thanks...!